# Mockito when/then not working

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to Mock `ValidatorService` in unit tests of `SubscriptionInterceptor`.

```
validator = Mockito.mock(ValidatorService.class);
Mockito.when(validator.validateSubscription(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn("");
interceptor = new SubscriptionInterceptor(validator);
```

Later, when the interceptor calls the `validateSubscription` method of the mocked validator, an instance of the actual class is invoked, rather than the mock. Why? How can I get the method call to return an empty String?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special for the empty string to be returned; it's the default return value as long as Mockito can stub the method, which it seems not to be able to do here. Can you confirm that both ValidatorService and validateSubscription are public and non-`final`?

Comment: Method was declared final. It works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved in comments:

> Method was declared final.

Mockito works by providing a proxy (subclass) of the class in question, with each of the methods overridden. However, for `final` classes and methods, Java assumes that it can detect which implementation it needs to call, and skips the dynamic method lookup. Because of this, Mockito cannot override behavior for `final` methods, `static` methods, or methods on `final` classes, and because you're not interacting with the mock Mockito cannot even warn you about it.

This is a very common problem; be sure to check for `final` fields if Mockito is not working for stubbing/verifying your method.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to remove `final`, `static` fields/classes/methods in main java sources you could put mocks initialization after mockito's "when/then" stubs.
It will call a constructor for the mock object with `final`s after all stubs initialization.

Try:

```
Mockito.when(validator.validateSubscription(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn("");
validator = Mockito.mock(ValidatorService.class);
interceptor = new SubscriptionInterceptor(validator);
```